# display contents of database in table

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im having trouble with displaying the contents of my database in a html table.
The table is created but it just has the headings, I did find another thread that was having the same issues but it seems that it is a different issue for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php 
        require_once 'db.php';

        if(isset($_POST['cyanxerox'])){$id = 1; }
        if(isset($_POST['magentaxerox'])){$id = 2;}
        if(isset($_POST['blackxerox'])){$id = 3;}
        if(isset($_POST['yellowxerox'])){$id = 4;}

        if(isset($id)){
            $sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE supplies SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE Id=".$id);
            $sth->execute();
            header('Location: index.php');
            die("Posted, now redirecting");
        }

        #this is the part that is not working
        $result = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name_of_supply, quantity, description from supplies');
        $result->execute();

        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id= $row['id'];
            $name_of_supply =  $row['name_of_supply'];
            $quantity = $row['quantity'];
            $description = $row['description']; 
        }




    ?>
    <title>Homepage</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ICT Support Printer Supplies Inventory</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="cyanxerox" value="Cyan Xerox"/>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="magentaxerox" value="Magenta Xerox"/>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="blackxerox" value="Black Xerox"/>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="yellowxerox" value="Yellow Xerox"/>
    </form>
    //this is the part that is not working
    <table>
        <thread>
            <th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Number in Stock</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </th>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td><? echo $id; ?></td>
                   <td><? echo $name_of_supply; ?></td>
                   <td><? echo $quantity; ?></td>
                   <td><? echo $description; }?></td>
                </tr>
                   <?#php endwhile ?>
            </tbody>
        </thread>
    </table>
</body>
```

EDIT: i added the code as the whole file, 
I  can also say that the sql query runs fine.

Comment: your table html and your db record fetching code are on two separate files or in the same file?

Comment: I have edited the post to inclue the whole php file. Sorry if its not been coded well, im a noob :P @AlivetoDie

Comment: In your while loop, you're just assigning value to variables, that's it.  After while loop ends, the variables will disappear because they're outside the scope of the while loop.

Comment: you don't need that many forms.

Comment: your code also contains quite a few errors

Comment: and you have a scoping issue here to which error reporting should be used and you'll see what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems in your code:**

1. If you're using p[repared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared) then you should also properly **bind the input values** to the input markers. Otherwise it makes no sense to prepare the SQL statements and you are fully exposed to [SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection).
2. You wrote `<thread>` instead of `<thead>` in html.
3. `<thead>`must be closed before `<tbody>`.
4. After `<thead>` comes `<tr>` not `<th>`.
5. You missed to write "php" inside the `td`s: `<td><?php echo $id; ?></td>`.
6. `<?#php endwhile ?>` is falsely placed. Remove it completely.
7. You have a falsely placed `}`in `<td><? echo $description; }?></td>`. Remove it.
8. Probably you would receive `Undefined index` notices for the `echo`s in table body. Check them for `isset`.

**My code proposals:**

- Activate [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) first, in order to be sure that no errors are raised, causing the absence of records in the html table.
- Use only one form with multiple submit buttons. All buttons have the same `name` attribute. Each button have the corresponding supply id as `value` attribute.
- Put no PHP code for handling the form submission or the db fetching operations in the `<head>` tag of `index.php`. Put in at the beginning of the page.
- Don't use that `Location` header. Bad idea.
- Fetch all db data in PHP arrays and read them inside the HTML code.
- Use `fetchAll()` instead of a `while` loop with `fetch()`.
- Always put the three `<meta>` tags that I provided inside the `<head>` tag of your html/php pages.

Good luck.

#### db.php

```
<?php

// Create the db connection.
$conn = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=tests;charset=utf8'
        , 'user'
        , 'pass'
        , array(
    // Important! Research on the subject "PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION".
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE
        )
);
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

/*
 * =========================
 * Activate error reporting.
 * =========================
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Set to 0 on the live server!
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/*
 * ====================================
 * Run operations upon form submission.
 * ====================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    $id = $_POST['submitButton'];

    /*
     * ======================
     * Update quantity by id.
     * ======================
     */
    $sth = $conn->prepare('UPDATE supplies SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE Id = :id');
    $sth->execute(array(
        'id' => $id
    ));

    /*
     * ===============
     * Fetch supplies.
     * ===============
     */
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name_of_supply, quantity, description from supplies');
    $sth->execute();
    $supplies = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Homepage</title> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>ICT Support Printer Supplies Inventory</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="1">Cyan Xerox</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="2">Magenta Xerox</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="3">Black Xerox</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="4">Yellow Xerox</button>
        </form>

        <br/><br/>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Number in Stock</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if (isset($supplies)) {
                    foreach ($supplies as $supply) {
                        $id = $supply['id'];
                        $nameOfSupply = $supply['name_of_supply'];
                        $quantity = $supply['quantity'];
                        $description = $supply['description'];
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $nameOfSupply; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $quantity; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would say to keep the PHP and HTML separate, but ignoring that for now, the issue is your loop and output aren't connected.

You have several issues, and you should review some HTML structure and has been corrected and commented as such.

- You have a `header` redirect after HTML is already displayed, so headers have already been sent. This should be moved to the top of the file (or another file preferably).
- `<thead>` encapsolates the head of a table, not `<thread>`
- Make sure to close all tags (`<html>`)

The issue for which you came here is corrected by moving the loop to inside the table body, and looping for each row. Given that you're not doing any manipulation, you don't need to store each value into a variable as you're doing, but it'll work either way.

Corrected code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php 
        require_once 'db.php';

        if(isset($_POST['cyanxerox'])){$id = 1; }
        if(isset($_POST['magentaxerox'])){$id = 2;}
        if(isset($_POST['blackxerox'])){$id = 3;}
        if(isset($_POST['yellowxerox'])){$id = 4;}

        if(isset($id)){
            $sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE supplies SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE Id=".$id); // This all but defeats the point of preparing statements, use bound parameters
            $sth->execute();
            header('Location: index.php'); // This won't work since you've already sent headers with the HTML code above this...
            die("Posted, now redirecting");
        }

        #this is the part that is not working
        $result = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name_of_supply, quantity, description from supplies');
        $result->execute();

        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id= $row['id'];
            $name_of_supply =  $row['name_of_supply'];
            $quantity = $row['quantity'];
            $description = $row['description']; 
        }
    ?>
    <title>Homepage</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ICT Support Printer Supplies Inventory</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="cyanxerox" value="Cyan Xerox"/>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="magentaxerox" value="Magenta Xerox"/>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="blackxerox" value="Black Xerox"/>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="yellowxerox" value="Yellow Xerox"/>
    </form>
    //this is the part that is not working
    <table>
        <thead> <!-- thead not thread -->
            <tr> <!-- should be a row, not th -->
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Number in Stock</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <?php
                while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
                    $id= $row['id'];
                    $name_of_supply =  $row['name_of_supply'];
                    $quantity = $row['quantity'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                <tr>
                   <td><? echo $id; ?></td>
                   <td><? echo $name_of_supply; ?></td>
                   <td><? echo $quantity; ?></td>
                   <td><? echo $description; }?></td>
                </tr>
                   <?php endwhile; // Table loop ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html> <!-- close your HTML tag -->
```